# Second Law of Thermodynamics Restatement with usable energy instead of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Is it technically accurate to state the [Second Law of Thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) as:

> "The total amount of usable energy only decreases in a closed system"

I ask because it doesn't evoke the term "entropy", which usually only confuses the average person.

Comment: (a) How do you define 'usable energy'? (b) do you dismiss Clausius's version of the law and Kelvin's version, neither of which uses entropy?

Comment: @PhilipWood (a) Maybe "potential energy" would be better? (b) I had no idea about these two definitions, thanks

Comment: (a) "Maybe "potential energy" would be better?". I think not: for example the energy of  a real gas at atmospheric density is largely kinetic (random movement of molecules). (b) I recommend that you have a look at the Clausius and Kelvin statements, as they are clear and precise, but you will need a bit of background, for example an understanding of the First Law of Thermodynamics.

Comment: What if we define "usable energy" as "energy that will ever be useful to perform work"

Comment: @Zeke1999 You are right in using term usable or unusable energy in context. Also using potential of a system to convert energy is decreasing. While the term entropy for randomness gives it statistical meaning.

Comment: @Zeke1999 What have you in mind for energy that CAN'T ever be useful to perform work? Can you think of an example? I can't.

Comment: @PhilipWood In the old days, "usable energy" was called "puisance motrice" but then the German language police came around and we lost the term.

Answer (score 3):

What you suggest is the so-called *[Exergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergy)*, a term introduced in the fifties for a concept (the available energy) that dates back to Gibbs. The decrease in exergy is the counterpart of the usual increase in entropy.

However, I notice that after more than sixty years, the concept of exergy has not substituted entropy. Entropy may be confusing for the average person, but exergy is by no means a simpler concept.

Comment: "Entropy may be confusing for the average person, but exergy is by no means a simpler concept." I completely agree with you but the problem is that the concept of "heat" is even more confusing. In a reversible process only the word "calorique" should ever be used and the word "heat" (or "chaleur") need be mentioned, if at all, only as an abbreviation to  describe exergy loss or equivalently the product of irreversible calorique with temperature at which Carnot's calorique is produced. If it is taught that way then zeke1999's question is automatically answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it technically accurate to state the Second Law of Thermodynamics as: "The total amount of usable energy only decreases in a closed (actually, *isolated*) system"

Yes, we can give the following *qualitative* interpretation of the above statement without explicitly mentioning entropy or exergy.

A non-equilibrium system is generally characterized by gradients of temperature, pressure and chemical potential. The classical example is a rigid insulated box divided into two parts, each in its own temperature, pressure, and with its own composition. If we remove the partition under the presence of gradients there will be transfer of mass and energy between the two parts until $T$, $P$ and $\mu$ are uniform. This is a statement of the second law: *the tendency of an isolated system is to reach a state in which no gradients of $T$, $%P$ or $\mu$ exist*.

At the same time, useful work can be extracted from a thermodynamic system only in the presence of *gradients*. A Carnot cycle needs *two* different pressures, work requires a $\Delta P$, osmotic work requires $\delta \mu$. We can produce work from a non equilibrium partitioning of the system, but not from a system that has reached equilibrium, this would have to be placed into contact with some other system at different $T$, $P$ and $\mu$. The dissipation of gradients is what Kelvin termed the ["heat death"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) of the universe.